# WPF C# button click event in code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, button, onclick

I have create a button in code behind , but how do i write their click event? is it MouseDown? like this ? Basically i want to detect if the button is being pressed then i populate a textbox with some text.

```
Button btn1 = new Button();
btn1.Content = qhm.Option1;
sp1.Children.Add(btn1);

if (btn1.MouseDown = true)
{
   tbox.Text = qhm.Option1;
}
```

Comment: No need for downvote imo, question is asked in a way that makes it easy to answer, even shows 'what have you tried'.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Like that:

```
Button btn1 = new Button();
btn1.Content = qhm.Option1;
btn1.Click += btn_Click;
sp1.Children.Add(btn1);


//separate method
private void btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    tbox.Text = qhm.Option1;
}
```

using lambda:

```
btn1.Click += (source, e) =>
{    
    tbox.Text = qhm.Option1;
};
```

you can now access local variables.

Comment: theres no other way to do it? because my tbox is in another method , i can't access tbox

Comment: There is. Check my edit. But your `tbox` has to be referenced in the same method where you are creating your button.

Answer (score 1):

```
..
btn1.Click += btn1_Click;

private void btn1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a click event like this:

```
        Button btn1 = new Button();
        btn1.Content = qhm.Option1;
        sp1.Children.Add(btn1);
        btn1.Click += btn1_Click;
```

Than you can edit the event method to add some text to your text box.

```
void btn1_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
           tbox.Text = qhm.Option1;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Register a handler for the click event:

```
btn1.Clicked += myHandler_Click;
private void myHandler_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  // your code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to subscribe to the click event:

```
Button btn1 = new Button();
btn1.Content = "content";
btn1.Click+=btn1_Click;
sp1.Children.Add(btn1);
```

```
private void btn1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("You clicked it");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking, can be achieved with no other than **Events**, find in the MSDN explanations about events and how can be used.

In C# there are several kinds of GUI Controls, like Button Control, that has a number of events, like for example: click, mouseover, mousedown, doubleclick etc. In the MSDN help you can find the list of events supported for every control, along with the properties and methods.

So in your case, you'll probably want something along the line,

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button button2 = new Button();
        //Load button in container


        //Loading events for control
        button2.Click += new EventHandler(button2_Click);
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Do Something
    }
```

So basically **button2.Click += new EventHandler(button2_Click);**, you are adding and EventHandler that points to button2_click, to the Click event of the newly created button.

I hope this helps!

happy Coding